# GCC alias attribute for C++ member functions

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, alias, abi

I am running into a portability issue on Linux due to a type change in a system header.  The siginfo_t type was changed from a named struct (struct siginfo) to an unnamed struct.  For me this changed between RHEL6 and RHEL7.

We use [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) in a few places and they have siginfo_t in a few publicly exposed interfaces.  The result is that code compiled on RHEL7 will not link against a library that was built on RHEL6.  For the time being, I need to support this.

In RHEL6, one problem function is typed as:

```
ACE_Event_Handler::handle_signal(int, siginfo*, ucontext*)
```

In RHEL7, it looks like this:

```
ACE_Event_Handler::handle_signal(int, siginfo_t*, ucontext*)
```

These get mangled into different symbols resulting in either a failure during linking or a symbol lookup failure at runtime.

A relatively simple solution is to use a function alias.  However, I do not want to modify the header file.  I'm struggling a bit because this is a virtual member function.

I tried doing this in Event_Handler.cpp on a version of ACE built on RHEL7:

```
struct siginfo;
ACE_Event_Handler::handle_signal(int, siginfo*, ucontext*)
__attribute__((
  alias("_ZN17ACE_Event_Handler13handle_signalEiP9siginfo_tP8ucontext")
));
```

With this, GCC complains that the function was not declared.  I was ultimately able to make this work, but only with this ugly hack:

```
extern "C" int _ZN17ACE_Event_Handler13handle_signalEiP7siginfoP8ucontext()
__attribute__((
  alias("_ZN17ACE_Event_Handler13handle_signalEiP9siginfo_tP8ucontext")
));
```

The 'extern "C"' is needed to prevent re-mangling the mangled name.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this without running into compiler complaints?

Comment: I'd say, do not expect C++ library build on RHEL6 to interoperate with RHEL7. It might (and if memory serves, it does) have different libstdc++. I'd say, use libraries built for specific platform.

Comment: @SergeyA I have been doing C++ development for a long time on RHEL and they do a fantastic job of maintaining backwards compatibility.  In this case, I am using Red Hat's devtoolset-4 which is compatible across these RHEL releases.  I am building ACE rpms across both versions to deal with this one compatibility issue.  I have a strong understanding on what it takes to maintain C++ ABI compatibility across RHEL releases.  I know how to make it work.  I am looking for advice on better ways to do it.  Note the question -- "Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?"

Comment: I have exactly the same problem between SLES11 and SLES15. I am porting an application to SLES15 and I have seen this error. I believe I will compile the library for SLES15, not using the old one though.